# Windows batch file error passing variable (.bat)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to loop recursively through all the files inside a folder.
I need to read the file name, abcd_somethingone_pqrs.csv is the file name pattern. I need to create a folder (if the folder does not exist) named somethingone and move the file into that folder. I have started writing the following code in a .bat.

```
FOR /R D:\MOE\MRs\batchfiles\01\ %%F in (*.*) do ( 
echo %%~nF
set newloc=%%~nF
echo %newloc%
)
```

The line1 prints the filenames in the folder correctly. But when I read it to the new variable newloc, always the line4 prints only the last file's name. Can anyone please realize what's going wrong here or propose me a method to do this.

Comment: Do you want all the `somethingone` files to end up in the same folder, or should there be one folder per directory level?

Comment: I need to create a seperate folder for each different 'somethingone'. for example, there can be files like abcd_somethingone_pqrs.csv, abab_somethingone_pqpq.csv, abcb_somethingtwo_pqrr.csv. So i need to categorize all somethingone files into a folder named somethingone. All somethingtwo name containing files to a folder named somethingtwo...

Comment: Either I'm misreading, or your first two sentences contradict each other. I get that there need to be different `something___` folders, but is there only one `somethingone` folder for every single somethingone csv that gets encountered?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Totally changed my answer and actually attempted to completely solve your overall problem instead of just the thing you were stuck on.

You'll have to update target_dir to wherever you want the files to go.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set source_dir=D:\MOE\MRs\batchfiles\01\
set target_dir=D:\something\

:: Recursively search the source directory for files
for %%A in (somethingone somethingtwo somethingthree) do (
    for /F "delims=" %%B in ('dir /a:-d /s /b %source_dir%*%%A*') do (
        REM if the directory does not exist, make it
        if not exist %target_dir%%%A mkdir %target_dir%%%A

        move %%B %target_dir%%%A
    )
)
```

---

You need to enable delayed expansion so that the variable value inside the `for` loop will propagate correctly.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R D:\MOE\MRs\batchfiles\01\ %%F in (*.*) do (
    echo %%~nF
    set newloc=%%~nF
    echo !newloc!
)
```

Comment: SomethingDark, thanks for the answer..., but now the line 4 prints only !newloc! for me.. No clue what's going wrong.

Comment: If you can help, I also need to know how to split the filename string with the delimiter "_" ( underscore) as I have mentioned in the above question.. Thank you...

Comment: @nadh - Off the top of my head, I'd go with http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html and set `"delims=_"`.